# A generalization of holomorphic functions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables

Assume that $U$ is an open set in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ and $A$ is a real $2\times 2$ matrix.

We define

$$\mathcal{S}_{A}=\{f:U\to \mathbb{C}\mid Df.A=A.Df  \}$$
where $Df$ is the $2\times 2$ Jacobian matrix of smooth  function $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^{2}\simeq \mathbb{C}$.

Every function with this property is called an $A$-holomorphic function.

**Example:** When $J=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, $\mathcal{S}_{J}$ is the space of (usual)  holomorphic functions.

> Assume that this vector space  $\mathcal{S}_{A}$ is closed under "uniform convergence on compact subsets of $U$". That is: Assume that $f_{n}$ is a sequence in $\mathcal{S}_{A}$ and $f_{n}$ converges to $f$, uniformly on compact  subsets of  $U$. Then $f$ must  be in $\mathcal{S}_{A}$.
>
> Does this imply that $A$ is in the form $$A=\begin{pmatrix} a&-b\\b&a \end{pmatrix}$$

The question is  motivated by the fact that the uniform limit of  a sequence of  holomorphic  functions is  a holomorphic  function.

Comment: I meant convergent power series whose coefficients are dual numbers and whose argument is a dual number variable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number
But nevermind, this alone does not suffice to produce a counterexample since your vector space $S$ is possibly much bigger.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: Do you know a first-order linear partial differential operator (of two variables) with constant coefficients, whose kernel is closed under compact convergence? :-) BTW, a PDE tag seems highly appropriate.

Comment: @July  With real coefficients?..I  do not know. but the  CR equation can be read as $f_{x}+if_{y}=0$. Thanks for your  suggestion of  new tag PDE, I add it:-)

Comment: Yes, with real coefficients. If we had one and a bit of luck, one might be able to reconstruct a counter-example $A$. (On the other hand, if $A$ were complex of any dim., things would have been much easier.)

Comment: The only other thing that comes to my mind is the following: if $C(A)$ denotes the centralizer subalgebra of $A$ in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, then, by smoothness, $f$ admits Taylor $C(A)$-expansion (not obvious!), meaning that the Taylor polynomial(s) has coefficients *and* argument in $C(A)$ and the Legendre remainder term has arguments in $C(A)$ (similar to my example above with the dual numbers replaced by the algebra $C(A)$). I've always wondered in which cases (other than over the complex numbers) the remainder term converges to 0 :-) Sorry, I could not be of much help.

Comment: @July : my 1st idea was that whenever $A$ is of a certain form (which one ? invertible ? $A A^T = D$ ?) then $f$ is a linearly stretched holomorphic function, and the "closed under compact convergence" part is obvious. Is it false ?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. What is the significance of 'linearly stretched'? As for the form of $A$, well, it suffices that $C(A)\cong\mathbb{C}$, I'm not sure if there is more explicit description. But $C(A)$ can also be isomorphic to the algebra of dual numbers or of the split-complex numbers, which are not as well behaved and where it seems there is a big gap between smooth and analytic functions (similarly to the real case), but somewhere inbetween compact convergence might hold, I don't know.

Comment: Actually, that last comment of mine implicitly produced a counter-example to your specific question :-) Take the complex structure $J$, conjugate it $UJU^{-1}$ for any $U\in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, and take the algebra $C(UJU^{-1})$. Since it is isomorphic to the complex numbers, you get equivalence between differentiability/smoothness and analyticity, hence closedness under compact convergence, but $UJU^{-1}$ is certainly not of the above form. In other words, write complex-analytic functions in matrix form and conjugate them by $U$.

Comment: @July: it works. You just need to scale the complex structure on the target in the reverse way. See my answer.

Comment: @WillieWong: Thanks! One question, though. If we take the space of conjugated analytic functions (written in matrix form), what exactly fails if we do not scale by $c$?

Comment: @July, see my edit below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple counterexample:

Suppose $f(x,y) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ is a holomorphic function. Then it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations
\begin{align}
u_x = v_y\\
v_x = -u_y 
\end{align}

Then the function $g(x,y) = \tilde{u}(x,y) + i \tilde{v}(x,y)$ given by 
\begin{align}
\tilde{u}(x,y) = \frac12 u(2x,y) \\
\tilde{v}(x,y) = v(2x,y) 
\end{align}
satisfies
\begin{align}
\tilde{u}_x = \tilde{v}_y \\
\tilde{v}_x = -4 \tilde{u}_y 
\end{align}
which is the same as $ A.D g = D g.A $ for 
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1/4 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

---

This example is obtained geometrically by doing a linear change of variables $(x,y) \mapsto (2x,y)$ on the domain and $(u,v) \mapsto (\frac12 u,v)$ on the co-domain and so all convergence and closure of holomorphic functions carry over unchanged.

More generally, the same procedure shows that for any $A$ of the form

$$ A = c P J P^{-1} $$

where $P\in GL(2)$ and $c\in \mathbb{R}_+$ the closure property asked for in the question holds.

---

[Edit to answer [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244074/a-generalization-of-holomorphic-functions/244091#comment601823_244074)]:

The correct way to think about the question is that the two copies of $A$ in the equation $A (Df) = (Df) A$ are not the same. One is the complex structure on the domain and the other is the complex structure on the codomain. If you conjugate the complex structure on the domain side ONLY what you get is $$ P A P^{-1} (Df) = (Df) A$$ where the second $A$ is unchanged because it is the complex structure on the codomain. To make the equation work as written, we then do the reverse conjugation on the complex structure of the codomain which changes the equation to $$ PA P^{-1} (Df) = (Df) P A P^{-1}$$
The action on the codomain side is the reverse (given by the inverse matrix) simply because covariance versus contravariance in the equation.

Comment: It seems I've misunderstood you the first time. The constant $c$ is a matter of taste, i.e. it is independent of the choice of $P$, right? (I thought at first that it depended on $P$, which baffled me a little :-) )

Comment: @July: yes. I included the constant $c$ since in the original post, the matrices don't have to have determinant $\pm 1$.

Comment: @WillieWong  Thank you very  much for  your  answer. But I do  not  understand the last part of  your  answer. Is  not $J$ the usual  complex  structure of  Euclidean  reagons in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$? And is not true to say that:" the preserving of this  almost  complex structure  by a  map  f is  equivalent to $DfJ=JDf$?I do not  understand that why  you think my  formulation is  not  a  good  way for thinking on this problem?Thanks  again for your very interesting answer.

Comment: @WillieWong  another question: What  about  odd dimensional  case; Is there a $3 \times 3$ matrix  $A$ for  which $\mathcal{S}_{A}$, the  space of  A_holomorphic  functions  from  $R^3\to R^3$ is  a  closed subset of  $C(R^3, R^3)$  with the topology of  unfiorm convergence on compact subsets.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I have no idea what your comment is trying to say. (1) $J$ is, as you defined, the matrix for the complex structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. (2) Why must $f$ be a self map? You certainly didn't specify that in your question. In the generality of your question it makes more sense to think about $f$ as a map between complex manifolds $(U,J)$ and $(V,J')$ each with its own complex structure, and think about the relation $(Df)J' = J(Df)$. You can of course restrict to the case where it is a self map, but you don't have to.

Comment: In the 3x3 case: note that $A$ must have a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ with eigenvector $v$. Then for any function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the function $f(x) = v \phi(v^Tx)$ satisfies $$A(Df) = (Df)A = \lambda vv^T \phi'(v^Tx)$$ Now just pick a sequence $\phi_n$ of $C^1$ functions that converges uniformly to function that is not differentiable.

Answer (score -3):

There is a counterexample:

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$,then $\mathcal{S}_{A}=\{f:U\to \mathbb{C}\mid \frac{d}{dx}f = \frac{d}{dy}f\}$.

$\mathcal{S}_{A}$ is closed, but $A$ is not like $\begin{pmatrix} a&-b\\b&a \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Why is $\mathcal{S}_{A}$ closed under uniform convergence on compacts?

Comment: @July  I agree with you on this  comment. Because in my  question the  convergence is meant $C^{0}$-convergent.

Comment: Also, for this particular $A$, we actually have $\mathcal{S}_{A}=\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_1=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f_2, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_2=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f_1\}$ (as a PDE system). The centralizer of $A$ is the set of matrices for which the diagonal has same entries and the anti-diagonal has same entries.